# Crystal Report Add Columns Dynamically based on Pivot Query Result

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report, pivot, addition

I am using VB.Net 2010 with Crystal Reports. I have designed a pivot query that returns the required summary information.

**NOTE**: I do not want to use cross tab because I need to display the information from right to left.

The following is a sample result:

[image]

Simply I am summarizing the number of employees for each rank for every nationality. That is when I modify any employee's nationality, that nationality will appear as a column in the result: PIVOT.

I designed a crystal report that uses the same query and display the same data.

I set the data source of the report to a command and added the query in the command, But here is the problem: The number of columns returned by the query are only those retrieved when running the query at design time! That is, if new employee from an other nationality is added to the database it would not be possible to be displayed in the report. Or even, the maximum number of columns as per the columns set is 3.

My question is:

How can I add these columns dynamically based on the number of columns returned by the pivot query?

**MODIFICATION:**
As per the suggestions below, I designed a crystal report that uses a dataset with one datatable "DataTable1" and added 6 columns: one for Rank that is fixed, and the other columns are for the possible nationalities that may exist in my employee data table as the following picture:
[image]

The question now is how display the data returned by the pivot query in these columns?
And how hide the other columns that no data are placed on them?

Comment: I think your problem can be solved easily if you add a mapping table to your data base for nationality of three columns lets say e.g. NationalityId, NationalityName and NationalityArabicName and in the table above add one column instead of the last three columns called FK_NationalityId holds the value of each Nationality linked with the mapping table in the SP that fills the report in that case you would not have to add a column to the report each time

Comment: Thank you Mr. Abdulrahman, But the above results is not a table, it is data returned by pivot query. Also I already have table with country names having the same columns that you mentioned. I also did not understand how can I display all nationalities based on you suggestion!

Comment: Al-Rajihi as for the displaying you can use inner join between tables, as for the main question i seem to miss understood the problem, do you need to show the count of the countries base on gradecode?? or you need to add columns to your report based on some conditions??

Comment: Not the count of countries. Basically I have employees table with column nationality that is a foreign key from country master table. I designed a query to get detailed summary of the grades and how many employee from each nationality in that grade, where the above picture shows sample result when running the query

Answer (score 2):

Only solution that I see would work without using `crosstab` is to create the report as many columns as possible from right to left and then conditionally show and hide as the new columns gets added from database.

Comment: Fair enough but how to do that programatically? I need some code please

Comment: unfortunately.. I can't provide any code as I work on Crystal as a standalone application not through VB.. I you need in crystal I can help you

Comment: Ok, I tried the following code in crystal in suppress formula: if isNull(columnName) true else false. But it does not work

Comment: Can you explain more... which column you want to hide and what column you are using

Comment: Assume I have in my employee data table 3 different nationalities and have 6 nationalities in my country data table. I designed then crystal report using dataset as datasource. I added all the possible columns. Now when running the report I will have the correct details and also the other 3 nationalities will have their columns appear: DataColumn4, DataColumn5 and DataColumn6. How to suppress these columns?

Comment: Sorry Mr. Siva, please have a look to modifications in the question

Comment: This case you need to have 6 supress conditions...i guess you have used column name but you need data in the column as supress condition

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports uses a static definition at design time. The dynamic option that i know is the cross tab. But it had not attended me in any situation, because there are a lot of design restrictions. If cross tab is good enough to you, stick to Siva's answer. Otherwise, try something similar to Abdulrahman_88's solution.

When i need to create dynamic columns, i simulate this behavior in a similiar way suggested by Abdulrahman_88. I will try to describe as i am used to, i mean, the data source is a .NET DataSet. You can adapt it to your case.

The simpler case, is to assume you have a max number of columns. In your case, a max number of nationalities.

First, i would create a XSD describing the columns:

- gradeCode
- Rank
- currGrade
- sequence
- nationality1
- nationalityDescription1
- nationality2
- nationalityDescription2
- ...
- nationalityN, where N is the max number of columns.
- nationalityDescriptionN

So, i would create a similar DataSet in my code and fill it. Note that you could do it in .NET using your pivot table query and a DataAdapter.

Then, i would use the XSD as my data source and design the report with fixed columns and suppress empty columns labels.

If you cannot assume a max number of countries, then you need a "trickier" solution: create a page column. But i works only if you want to break page when the number of columns is wider than the page.

Tell me if you want to try it and need more details.

<s>[Here is a link for a full example in .NET](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxb3pxCHYFrudHY1VHNGUF9DaXc/view?usp=sharing).</s>
(not avaliable 5 years later, sorry)

Comment: Yes Mr. Heringer Thank you for your answer. I have modified the question as per the suggestions. Please have a look to the modifications and need your more details

Comment: Are you programming it in .NET?

Comment: May you post your query?

Comment: Yes, I am VB.Net Developer

Comment: so, did you check the example that i did put in the answer (link)?

Comment: I did, but its in C# and am not very much familiar with that environment

Comment: Can I get some other link for this solution as a given link is not working?
I am facing similar problem

Comment: I'm sorry, I looked for it, but the file does not exist anymore :( Let me know if I can help you with some specific issue.